# fetch value from SQL query list

Tags: java, sql, list

So i just wrote down this SQL query and i am trying to capture the value of rest_id in query.list(). However, this is giving the value as [1] . I want just 1 without the braces. How do i do it? Please check the code below for reference:

```
    String sql1 = "select rest_id from rest_details where rest_name = '" + nameclicked + "' and rest_location = '" +locclicked + "'" ; 
SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(sql1); 
System.out.println("sql1 " + query1.list());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to get the element inside list:

```
System.out.println("sql1 " + query1.list().get(0));
```

This always returns only the first element from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 System.out.println("sql1 " + query1.list());
```

By :

```
for(String id : query1.list() ) System.out.println("sql1 " + id);
```

Comment: if there will be always only one element, no need to loop

Comment: @Rajesh my answer is general not specific to his question , if he has more than one result , he should loop over this list.